# SSL pinning using AFNetworking sends NSURLErrorDomain -1012

Tags: ios, ssl, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to communicate with a web service using a pinned SSL self-signed certificate here is the setting for `AFSecurityPolicy`:

```
- (AFSecurityPolicy *)securityPolicy
{
    NSString *caPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ca" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSString *clientPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"client" ofType:@"cer"];
    NSData *caData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:caPath];
    NSData *clientData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:clientPath];

    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc]init];
    securityPolicy.pinnedCertificates = @[caData,clientData];
    securityPolicy.SSLPinningMode = AFSSLPinningModeCertificate;

    securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

    return securityPolicy;
}
```

I'm using an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` like the following:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://someurl"]]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
    }];
    operation.securityPolicy = [self securityPolicy];
    [operation start];
```

I have the **ca** and **client** certificates in the application Bundle, but it doesn't seem to work, I tried pretty much everything I could find with no success.

The output is :

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed.

PS: `validatesCertificateChain = NO` doesn't help.

I'm using the latest version of AFNetworking.

**UPDATE**

For the sake of testing I tried querying the server using libcurl for iOS, and the connection went through after few hiccups using the P12 certificate:

```
CURLcode res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

_curl = curl_easy_init();
if(_curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "annoying https url");


    curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0L);

    curl_easy_setopt(_curl,CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD,"p12 password");


    const char *pCertFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"client" ofType:@"p12"].UTF8String;
    const char *pCACertFile= [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"ca" ofType:@"crt"].UTF8String;

    curl_easy_setopt(_curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,pCertFile);
    curl_easy_setopt(_curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO,pCACertFile);


        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(_curl);
        /* Check for errors */ 
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));
        /* we are done... */

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(_curl);
}

curl_global_cleanup();
```

So this means that after all the certificates are okay, and the problem is somewhere else, someone have an insight ?

**PS:** re-writing the app and the use of curl is not an option since my internship ends next week, I really want a solution to this using AFNetworking since the app is already created accordingly.

Comment: If you know what the server certificate is supposed to be, then there's no need to pin the CA too. Try with just the server certificate.

Comment: It doesn't work this way neither

Comment: @Ayu, did you manage to solve this problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @vburojevic Nope sorry, we switch the security on the WebService in a way that I could finish the project on time. And I don't know what they did since.